# Webpack throws error on React image import

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to implement SSR using React (create-react-app) and Firebase. To do so, I'm currently working on my `webpack` configuration following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/82tZAPMHfT4) and [github dir](https://github.com/davideast/react-ssr-firebase-hosting):

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    }
}];
```

I have an assets folder with some images. Somehow for all imports, `webpack` returns the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/images/capture_5_move_on/1.JPG 1:0
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./src/shared/data.js 28:0-59 78:9-12
     @ ./src/modules/CartHolder/CartHolderMobile.js
     @ ./src/App.js
     @ ./src/index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a file loader for images: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader.

Somehow like this:

```js
module.exports = [{
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank's, the error's gone. Anyways, do you happen to know how the resolve the `state = {` (error pointing at `=`) syntax error? Browsing the web I found that I need to install `plugin-proposal-class-properties` - but how do I specify this in my webpack config?

Comment: You are welcome! I think you need Babel for that. Babel will transpile new ECMAScript syntax to plain javascript statements. After that webpack will bundle the transpiled code. I'm trying to find a tutorial for you right now, this is the best I could find so far: https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-babel-setup-tutorial

Comment: Thanks! I already setup babel, but it's still returning this error. You can find my setup and new question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520769/webpack-throws-syntaxerror-using-react-state